# Почему "расспросить" пишется с двумя С?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, корень-слова

Понятно, приставка рас-, но почему корень не -прос-, а -спрос-? Словарь Тихонова на мой вопрос не отвечает.

Answer (score 2):

Просить — **с**просить — **рас**спросить.
[**Рас/с/прос/и/ть**](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):
**рас-** и **с-** — приставки; **-прос-** — корень; **-и** — суффикс; **-ть** — глагольное окончание.

Немного другой разбор [здесь](http://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%A0/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), но смысл тот же: в этом слове две приставки.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь действительно две приставки и корень "прос". Тихонов именно такой разбор и дает.

Но тут даже не в этом дело.
Какой бы мы корень не выделяли ("прос" или "спрос" - что не не так уж и абсурдно), у образований на "прос" и "спрос" принципиально разные значения, сравните ***выпросить*** и  ***выспросить***. 
Понятно, что "расспросить" восходит к "спрос", к тому что спрашивают, а не просят.

Особняком, правда, стоит слово "вопрос", но это объясняется древностью образования слова, оно тех времен, когда значение "просить" еще несло в себе оба понятия - и "просить," и "спросить". Другими словами, приставка "во-" здесь играет туже роль что и "с" в "спросить" - она не просто конкретизирует смысл корня, но меняет его на достаточно в современном понимании далекий.